Why does redis report no subscribers to a channel after I subscribe to that channel without errors?
I am trying to send realtime feedback over websockets, and I'm doing that by sending data over redis from a rest-api server to a websocker server (both written in python/django). In the websocket server, I subscribe to a channel named "events" like this:
redis_connection = redis.Redis(
    host=settings.REDIS_HOST,
    port=settings.REDIS_PORT,
    db=settings.REDIS_CACHE_DB,
)
pubsub = redis_connection.pubsub()
pubsub.subscribe(events=process_event)

In the rest-api server, I publish data to the same redis channel like this:
connection.publish("events", json.dumps({"user_email": user.email, "message": message}))

While trying to figure out why no events ever made it to the "process_event" handler, I found that the publish method returns the number of subscribers to a channel, so I updated that line to this:
count = connection.publish("events", json.dumps({"user_email": user.email, "message": message}))
print(f"Published to events channel with {count} subscribers")

The result is always 0, even after the subscription above. I went inside the redis-stack Docker container saw the following when I directly tried to query the subscriber count:

redis-cli
127.0.0.1:6379> PUBSUB NUMSUB events

"events"
(integer) 0



127.0.0.1:6379>

The logs of the redis-stack itself doesn't seem to recognize any subscription or publication. However, if I use the command "redis-cli monitor" I see both show up:

1727460056.950779 [0 172.17.0.1:58210] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-NAME" "redis-py"
1727460056.952892 [0 172.17.0.1:58210] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-VER" "5.0.8"
1727460056.954072 [1 172.17.0.1:58210] "SELECT" "1"


1727460056.956442 [1 172.17.0.1:58210] "SUBSCRIBE" "events"


1727460122.677189 [0 172.17.0.1:45874] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-NAME" "redis-py"
1727460122.678973 [0 172.17.0.1:45874] "CLIENT" "SETINFO" "LIB-VER" "5.0.8"
1727460122.681286 [1 172.17.0.1:45874] "SELECT" "1"


1727460122.683120 [1 172.17.0.1:45874] "PUBLISH" "events" "{"user_email": "admin@domain.com", "message": "Message content"}"

After all that, PUBSUB NUMSUB events still gives the same result.

Which redis client you use? Does the connection stay alive between the sub to publish?

I think it's the standard one for python. You can see the creation of a connection above ("redis_connection = redis.Redis"), and the source of that redis library was just an "import redis" line.

So for why you don't get any event running is because it is not like socket, you don't get push notification, the pubsub object you created need to pull the messages:
redis_pubsub.get_message()
For why, you get 0 on NUMSUB — I suspect that your client is not connected when you send the message. 
You have two processes running, and the sub client get closed when the service goes to sleep or get cleaned since it has no more tasks (if you don't give it any other task later on, like checking if a message arrived, it might get out of scope and be dropped).
To follow-up comments:

it kept erroring out with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv_into'

I need to see your function, but possibly the issue is that subscribing to a channel is also a message sent on the channel. 
If you don't handle it or config to not get it, you might have error with parsing etc. 
You can avoid getting those messages using redis_connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True). 
But this is an assumption, I need to see the code to give the right answer.

The docstring for subscribe says: """ Subscribe to channels. Channels supplied as keyword arguments expect a channel name as the key and a callable as the value. A channel's callable will be invoked automatically when a message is received on that channel rather than producing a message via listen() or get_message(). """

The meaning is when you'll call one of those, instead of getting the message it automatically will trigger your handler. A smart way to do so without blocking the main thread is using something like:
pubsub.subscribe(events=process_event)

def exception_handler(ex, pubsub, thread):

    print(ex)

    thread.stop()

    thread.join(timeout=1.0)

    pubsub.close()

thread = pubsub.run_in_thread(exception_handler=exception_handler)

So you can run in separate thread plus adding error handling to the thread.

The docstring for subscribe says:
"""
Subscribe to channels. Channels supplied as keyword arguments expect
a channel name as the key and a callable as the value. A channel's
callable will be invoked automatically when a message is received on
that channel rather than producing a message via listen() or
get_message().
"""
When I tried adding calls to get_message after that subscription, it kept erroring out with "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'recv_into'"

On the other hand, PUBSUB NUMSUB did start reporting 1 instead of 0.

Edit my answer with follow up

It's slightly confusing to respond to an edit rather than a new comment, but this is the line that causes the error:
pubsub.get_message(ignore_subscribe_messages=True)
This is the line at the bottom of the stack trace where an NPE occurs:
bufflen = self._sock.recv_into(self._buffer)
Thus, self._sock appears to be None in hiredis.py's read_from_socket function.

You don't use ignore_subscribe_messages=True when you call to get_message, you do so when creating the pubsub object  — redis_connection.pubsub(ignore_subscribe_messages=True).  When the comment is too long, I have no choice but to add it as an answer, and SOF don't like you to create more than one answer.

This is the signature of the method, ignore_subscribe_messages is an expected parameter:
def get_message(
self, ignore_subscribe_messages: bool = False, timeout: float = 0.0
):

If self._sock is none that's mean that you are not connected anymore and when the library tries to get the message from socket to parse it there's no socket. So you have a connectivity issue. If you want further help, I need to see larger pieces of the code.

Understanding the issue by the bottom of the stack trace is a bit challenging.

When I put the get_message command inside a try-catch block that just ignores any error, it started working. Maybe there's a delay before get_message starts working?

If the call to get message initiated before the connection established and the socket is alive it will throw an error, so yea, a delay is possible. I think in any case error handling would be a good idea all over the usage. So everything is working now?

If you're interested in a library with responsive team and direct support take a look at ValKey-Glide you can chat with us is directly on Valkey discord, we also provide pubsub restoration in case of disconnections, which is a rare and important feature. So take a look:)

I can confirm that adding a 30 second delay also removed the error.

Great, so they probably don't have an error handling when connection wasn't established yet, and you needed to create it by yourself
